# Evidence for segmental phonology in the acoustic speech signal

Tags: phonology, phonetics, spoken-language, acoustic-analysis, suprasegmentals

**What evidence for segmental phonology could be found in the acoustic speech signal?**

I think the parameters of acoustic speech signals include f0, amplitude, duration, wave form, etc., which are correlated with suprasegmental aspects of speech. Then how the speech signal provide evidence for segmental phonology?
(Perhaps something related to place of articulation and VOT?)

Answer (score 1):

The physical properties of the speech signal do *not* provide evidence for phonological analysis into a system of categories, which might include "segment". If you want evidence for the segment, or for features, you have to look to the mind that causes the speech signal to exist. There are occasional contexts where you can *detect* segment boundaries by looking for types of acoustic events in the speech signal, but we only know to look for them because we know in advance that there are segments, and we can develop theories of what the acoustic correlates of certain segments are.